# How to enable environment manager in spring-boot-admin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-admin

I have a couple spring-boot applications (clients) and one spring-boot-admin. I would like to manage environment variables in my clients applications but by default spring-boot-admin-starter-client and spring-boot-admin-starter-server does not support this feature (v1.5.2).

In my SBA I see logs, metrics etc. except environment management. I tried spring-cloud-commons and eureka but it doesn't seem to work. 
Can someone tell me, which extensions (spring-cloud, etc.) are required?

Comment: Problem solved.  Helped 
`<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>` in client application

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `spring-cloud-starter` maven dependency. The AutoConfiguration should take care of activating the `EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint`

Comment: Your answer is correct as `spring-cloud-starter` transitively brings in `spring-cloud-context ` making @jakub-Świeca comment (answer) more correct, if one prefers to only bring in dependencies that are going to use.